# Is it ok to break long html elements down into multiple lines?

Tags: html

I often see very long code lines like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
```

Is it ok to break them down like:

```
<input type="email" 
       name="email" 
       autocomplete="email" 
       id="email_address" 
       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" 
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" 
       class="input-text" 
       data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' 
       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
>
```

Because this makes it much clearer and easier to read in my opinion.

I usually do this if there are more than about 80-100 chars.

---

Validation with https://validator.w3.org/

[image]

Comment: Does it still work? Do HTML validators have a problem with it? If the first is a yes and the second a no, I'd recommend breaking it up over the original long line.

Comment: @Mast, yes it still works and it validates correctly. I think this answers the question :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd already answered this in the comments (which I shouldn't, we got answer fields for this), but anyway...

> Because this makes it much clearer and easier to read in my opinion.

Absolutely. And that's a good reason to do it. Your 80-100 character limit makes sense as well. 80 is considered a standard 'limit' of sorts in many languages (Python is famous for it, but back in the day punch cards and teletypes were already limited to 80 columns).

Google's [HTML style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Line-Wrapping) states:

> Break long lines (optional).
>
> While there is no column limit recommendation for HTML, you may consider wrapping long lines if it significantly improves readability.
>
> When line-wrapping, each continuation line should be indented at least 4 additional spaces from the original line.

You've already verified your [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) doesn't have a problem with it either, so, go for it. In hindsight, if the validator would've had problems with it, it would've been time for a better validator.

Better readability => better maintainability => less bugs and less development time.